# Why is there so much variation allowed on the import's module-name?

Tags: javascript, es6-module-loader

I'm reading about javascript's new [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and for the module name it says this (emphasis mine):

> module-name: The module to import from. This is *often* a relative or absolute path name to the .js file containing the module, excluding the .js extension. Certain bundlers *may permit or require the use of the extension; check your environment.*

Why is there so much variability in this?  Is the language providing this feature or is it delegating to 3rd party libraries to do it for you?  I'm inferring the latter.

Why doesn't this cause a slew of issues?  For example, I import a library that uses bundler x.  It internally uses extensions.  But my code uses bundler y.  It does not use extensions.  If I try to use this library, won't the code break?

This must not be as big a deal as I'm making it out to be.  Can someone explain how it all works out in the end?  How come I don't have to change my bundler for the library I want to use?

Comment: Well bundlers can always give you out options to handle out the file resolution. Surprisingly there isn't a major variation with module specifiers for most libraries out there. Sometimes you are really just forced to use the library bundler though. RN has this problem I think, it has its own bundler because its uses their own module specifiers (and possibly some other stuff).

Comment: @MinusFour I find this unusual.  Usually when a language catches up to the features other libraries had to backfill, it *replaces* them.  What's the value in providing these language keywords if it's still "the wild west" when it comes to certain implementation details?

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. No, it wouldn't break. "Is the language providing this feature or is it delegating to 3rd party libraries to do it for you? I'm inferring the latter" The answer is neither, right now. Module bundlers like Webpack or Rollup have to handle many different possible import strings. Although the specification should be implemented by browser so (theoretically) a bundler won't be necessary in the future.

Comment: "a bundler won't be necessary in the future".  That's what I wanted to hear!  OK, that text gives no such indication.  In fact, I think it implies the opposite.  I think I could consider that as an answer.

Comment: The problem is we are still writing ES6 modules when there hasn't been a valid loader and the efforts for standardization are still in progress. You will require a bundler in the near future because you'll always want a fallback through a script for environments that can't parse modules. So this is a legitimate concern.

Comment: Moved most of my comments to an answer

Comment: By extensions do you mean specifiers with `.js`, `.mjs`, etc? or plugins?

Comment: @MinusFour I think it means the former.

Comment: @DanielKaplan, extensions should really be the least of your poblems to be honest, at least for bundlers. Most of them should let you configure what extensions to look for. Some native loaders might require you to specify the extensions (once we get them).

IMO your biggest obstacle would be for bundlers that absolutely do weird stuff with the specifiers. Like webpack inline loaders.

Comment: The majority of the things being distributed in NPM are in the nodejs module format and they follow the `resolve` algorithm for nodejs modules. You'd only really run into this problem if you get the source manually and use the bundler on that.

Answer (score 1):

> I import a library that uses bundler x. It internally uses extensions. But my code uses bundler y. It does not use extensions. If I try to use this library, won't the code break?

Files need extensions, so that's universal across bundlers.

But I see your point. There are many code bundlers, and several specs (commonJS, UMD, etc). They may not be compatible, but generally bundlers try to support as much as possible.

Now, there's an official ecmascript specification, which should be implemented by browsers, so (theoretically) a bundler won't be necessary in the future.

The module spec was created a a few (?) years ago, but only a few browsers support it: https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module. For better or for worse, I expect bundlers to be around for several more years at least, to get around implementation issues that browsers may have, for language transpiling, code minifying, and (of course) backwards compatibility for old browsers.

Comment: Looked at that a bit and it seems to be for the `<script>` tag.  Is that the same thing?

Comment: Yes, that's how you'd use modules in a browser. You add `type="module"` to the script tag.

Comment: It might very well break outside browser environments just by using the wrong extension. Some environments can opt for loading scripts as modules if they use `.mjs` extensions which can break out your scripts and viceversa.